# Como criar um vetor de strings em C?

Tags: c

Meu codigo está dando erro nas linhas 15 e 53

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    struct datas{

        int dia;
        int mes;
        int ano;

        char meses[12] = {'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'};


    };

    struct datas data;

    printf("\nInforme a data:\n\n");

    printf(" Dia..: "); scanf("%i", &data.dia); 
    printf(" Mês..: "); scanf("%i", &data.mes);
    printf(" Ano..: "); scanf("%i", &data.ano);

    //verificação de erros

    if(data.dia >31|| data.dia<1)
    {
        printf("Uma mês tem no máximo 31 dias\nTente novamente.");  sleep(3);   system("cls");
        main(); 
    }

    else if(data.mes >12 ||data.mes <1)
    {
        printf("Um ano tem 12 meses\nTente novamente.");    sleep(3); system("cls");
        main();
    }

    else if(data.ano < 1900 || data.ano > 3000)

    {
        printf("Valor de ano fora da realidade\nTente novamente."); sleep(3);   system("cls");
        main();
    }

    system("cls");



    printf("\nHoje é dia %i de %s de %i\n\n", data.dia, data.meses[data.mes], data.ano);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o erro seja causado por isso:

`char meses[12]`

Como um char representa um caractere, quando você aponta para `meses[31]`, ou algo assim, você está apontando para algo que não existe. Não sou experiente em C, mas, se seguir a lógica do Java, eu substituiria por isso:

`char meses[12][20]`

Onde, segundo minha lógica bizarra, você poderia ter 12 strings de 20 caracteres, ou algo do tipo.

Obs.: e se você usasse enumeradores pra os meses, não daria mais estabilidade? No Java funciona (como eu disse, sou novo no C, então minha lógica pode soar um pouco esquisita às vezes)...

Answer (score 2):

Talvez seja melhor essa implementação de sua strut: Primeiro: Colocar a matriz de meses fora da struct, e a matriz deve possuir a quantidade de registros e o tamanho máximo de cada um (char matriz[quat valores][tam max]), da forma que você esta implementando, isso fica mais claro quando se usa alocação em memória com malloc. Espero que tenha te ajudado.

```
struct datas{
int dia;
int mes;
int ano;
};
struct datas data;

char meses[12]10] = "Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro"};
```